# Snowflake how to call External Function in Snowpark

Tags: python, sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, data-warehouse

I want to call an External Function defined in Snowflake from Snowpark python code. For example, I am trying to manipulate the dataframe like this:

`dataframe = dataframe.with_column('name', sql_expr("select test_ext(3,4)"))`

However the input to the function `sql_expr` is not getting recognized by the python interpretor.
(Here, test_ext() is an External Function which integrates with Azure.)

```
syntax error line 1 at position 85 unexpected 'select'.
syntax error line 1 at position 103 unexpected '4'.
```

Am I using the syntax correctly? The official docs do not give any examples for `sql_expr`

Comment: try this ```dataframe.with_column('name', test_ext(3,4))```

Comment: Not working @aek

Comment: Thanks, could you please add the error to your question?

Comment: Added original error @aek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not reproduce the same error, but it should work like below:

1. You need to use the module function:

```
from snowflake.snowpark.functions import function
```

2. Create a function object from your ext function:

```
test_ext = function("test_ext")
```

3. Then you should be able to  call it like:

```
dataframe = dataframe.with_column('name', test_ext(3,4))
```